# Unable to resize column in chrome dev tools Resources

Tags: android, realm, google-chrome-devtools, stetho

So I have an android project in which I am using realm. The issue being that my design has a lot of columns listed in one particular table. Sadly I can't seem to see all of them and I can't resize it is there a horizontal scroll I can use I'm not sure how to handle this?

[image: an image of my realm]

Comment: I know this is no help but I am in the same boat.  It is pretty frustrating.

Comment: I got around this by expanding the whole window to another monitor.  It's a pain though because there is no horizontal scroll.  I have to drag the entire window around.

Answer (score 3):

There's no horizontal bar, but you can use these two options to help read the db data (if you don't have an extra screen):

1. Zoom out using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
2. You can perform SQL queries to select a subset of columns by clicking on the database icon and writing the query on the right panel.

Comment: Tried the zoom out option, still better than nothing…
Thanks for the tip